# How can I check button has class disabled?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, testcase

I have two buttons. If one button has class disable than other hasn't. Now I want to check that if first button has class disable than I need to click on second button and vice-versa.

I am trying with below code but it is returning every time true. Disable class is added dynamically depends on condition.

```
if (expect(element(by.css('ul#menu [data-selector="holdInventory"]'))
.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('disabled')) {
    console.log('has class');
} else {
    console.log('has not class');
}
```

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[class=disabled]') https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: Its not jquery. It's angularjs. I am using with protractor.

Comment: querySelectorAll is a JS function and has nothing todo with jQuerry. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: I want to check that first button has class disable or not. If yes than I need to click second button and vice-versa.

Comment: if(angular.element(myElement).hasClass('disabled'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In protractor everything is a promise. So in order to perform an operation you need to resolve it first and then validate the class value. Also you cannot use equal because an element can be associated with multiple classes so you need to make use of includes instead.

```
var btn1 = element(by.css('ul#menu [data-selector="holdInventory"]'));
btn1.getAttribute('class')).then(function(cls) {
  if(cls.includes('disabled')) {
    btn1.click();
  } else {
    btn2.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can I ask more help?

Comment: Sure..I would love to help

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length is `1` of the elements by querying all as below,

```
let  elements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('ul#menu [data-selector="holdInventory"]');
expect(elements.length).toEqual(1); //////////////
```

Comment: How can I use with if/else?

Comment: how to import fixture in angular1?

Comment: if/else as in can you elaborate ? `import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/testing'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to add class of disable dynamically with some condition like this

```
<button ng-class="{'disable' : switchDisable == '1'}"> Disable </button>
<button ng-class="{'disable' : switchDisable == '0'}"> Not Disable</button>
```

Here `switchDisable` Is a scope value which you can toggle on click of the button like `$scope.switchDisable = 1` or you can use any other expression as you like.
Reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: It's perfect for angularjs. But when you are using protractor, you can't use like this. I want to match class for test case.